# Social Login Not Working

Tags: social-connected, login

We have Sitecore 8.0 with Update 5. Social Login used to work fine till yesterday. Its not working today. Is it because it is using Graph API 2.2 and it is obsoleted on 27th March? What is the better workaround  for this?

Comment: There is no exact fix for this issue. Facebook API version(v2.2) was hard coded in "Sitecore.Social.Facebook.Connector.Paths.FacebookPathsFactory". Sitecore suggested to upgrade to latest version 8.2. Alternatively, Sitecore also suggested to use Sitecore social DLLs from Sitecore 8.2 version. However this approach may cause DLL version mismatch issues.

Comment: Check the further details at http://sitecorenj.blogspot.in/2017/04/social-connected-facebook-api-fix.html